# Wordpress Page as a Content Node

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a homepage with blocks of content that would be more easily handled by grabbing content from multiple pages for better organization on the backend. The problem is that I do not want to create actual pages, just use the content (similar to Private page stutus, but visible to everyone).

Is there a way to setup a custom status or post type so that I can create content nodes that can be used to aggregate on the homepage? (Basically like a page as a large widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a custom post type.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types

Custom post types can have their own properties, their own UI for editing in the admin side, yet can be retrieved with the same functions you use to retrieve normal posts and pages, so that you can easily insert them into your theme.

Comment: I am aware of Custom Post Types, but can these be hidden from all views / sitemaps / etc. except when explicitly queried? I don't want any accessible links to be created for the posts.

Comment: Thanks Dan! After digging into the Custom Post API a little more I found just the settings I needed setting Public and Publicly Queryable to false. Works like a charm. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you just need content blocks, why not add an [options page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) and use [the_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_editor) to handle the html content. You can then retrieve the content by grabbing the options, without creating additional single, archive or feed content.

If you're not familiar with the [settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), [Otto](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/) did a good article on it.